# Chrome freezes for ~60 seconds after first open when Windows 10 starts up

Tags: windows-10, boot, google-chrome, freeze

After I boot up Windows 10 and go to start Chrome, I get about 5 seconds of functionality and then Chrome freezes for about 60 seconds or more. I can open new tabs but they don't load anything. I cannot interact with any existing tab contents. During that time I can't open settings, view extension or open Developer Tools but I am able to open Chrome's Task Manager.

- No other apps lag or freeze in this time period
- I've tried deleting `/AppData/Local/Google/Chrome/User Data/` (This removes all extensions)
- I've tried a completely fresh install of Chrome
- Firefox and IE11 are unaffected by this issue as well as all other apps
- It happens even with Hardware Acceleration disabled
- Chrome Canary is not affected by the bug
- Happens even on chrome://settings page
- Disabled internet. Still happens on tabs trying to open chrome://settings
- Disabled a bunch of the services under "Privacy and security"

What could be potential causes of this problem? What are some things I can do to troubleshoot this issue?

*I recently upgraded my computer (new motherboard, CPU and RAM) and it was after that time but I don't know if it started immediately with the new machine.*

Comment: Have you checked to see if the same problem occurs utilizing another browser:  Internet Explorer or Firefox?

Comment: start chrome without any extensions and look if you still have the same issue or not

Comment: @magicandre1981 thanks for the idea but I've already tried that. I've edited the question to reflect that.

Comment: @Run5k other browsers and apps work fine

Comment: Is it happening only after booting up the system or everytime you open or close the chrome?

Comment: @Ali786 it only happens after a fresh boot

Comment: @PimpJuiceIT started chat here https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/75957/chrome-sucks

Comment: Have you tried preventing chrome from running in the background?

Answer (score 2):

Try also this :

1. [Disable Hardware Acceleration](https://www.lifewire.com/hardware-acceleration-in-chrome-4125122)
2. Disable your antivirus
3. Try [Chrome Canary](https://www.google.com/chrome/browser/canary.html) - the future developer version of Chrome with the latest updates.

Comment: 1. Still afters after. 2. I just use Windows Defender, haven't tried yet. 3. Canary seems unaffected.

Comment: If Canary is working, you might keep on using it until it becomes the stable version.

Answer (score 2):

Worked for me:

go to apps; select microsoft edge; advance options; then select reset.  The other think I did was uninstall Intel Optain pinning if installed.

I have been looking for solutions to this for a month. I tried every recommendation (you know them you've tried). I was noodling around saw these decided to do what I recommended and BAM!, chrome loads instantly.

Hope this helps and works for you.

Answer (score 1):

In addition to what you've tried:

- Go to Settings and clear all saved data, including cached data, saved passwords, and cookies
- close all browsers
- Restart the machine

If the problem recurs, run a boot-time scan with your antivirus program to make sure you don't have a rootkit installing nonsense into Chrome.

Comment: Virus scan didn't show anything and tried a clean install of Chrome. I just don't know where to look or what to look at

Comment: Was it a scan that runs at boot before Windows can load?

Comment: yeah it was a Windows Defender "Offline Scan" that runs before bootup